# MapKit in iOS 8 not run

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8, mapkit

I am building an iOS application that display a POI in a MapView, but firstly I can display the map, and with iOS8 this is begin a problem.
I read a lot question in this site, but none run on my app even if the code seems right.

I entered into myapplicationTest-info.plist the following code

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
```

And the code in the file.m is this:

```
#import "MapViewController.h"

#define IS_OS_8_OR_LATER ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)

@interface MapViewController ()

@end

@implementation MapViewController
@synthesize mapView = _mapView ;


- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.mapView.delegate = self;
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
if (IS_OS_8_OR_LATER) {
    //[self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
}

   [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

   self.mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
   [mapView setMapType:MKMapTypeStandard];
   [mapView setZoomEnabled:YES];
   [mapView setScrollEnabled:YES];
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:YES];

    self.locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone; //Whenever we move
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    NSLog(@"%@", [self deviceLocation]);

    //View Area
    MKCoordinateRegion region = { { 0.0, 0.0 }, { 0.0, 0.0 } };
    region.center.latitude = self.locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude;
    region.center.longitude = self.locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude;
    region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.005f;
    region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.005f;
    [mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];

}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
{
    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(userLocation.coordinate, 800, 800);
    [self.mapView setRegion:[self.mapView regionThatFits:region] animated:YES];

}
- (NSString *)deviceLocation {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"latitude: %f longitude: %f", self.locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude, self.locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude];
}
- (NSString *)deviceLat {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", self.locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude];
}
- (NSString *)deviceLon {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", self.locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude];
}
- (NSString *)deviceAlt {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", self.locationManager.location.altitude];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@end
```

Where is the mistake?

Why it doesn't run?

Comment: r u add keys in plist

Comment: I've already set them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide a value for `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` key which is the string that describes why your app wants to use location services -

For example -

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>FindMeDonuts will use your location to identify nearby donut shops</string>
```

Also, rather than checking the iOS version, it is better to check if CLLocationManager responds to the authorisation selector  -

```
if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)]) {
        [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
}
```

finally, this won't stop your map from updating, but it doesn't make sense - you are assigning a delegate to your `CLLocationManager` before you allocate and initialise it.

You should say -

```
self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
self.locationManager.delegate=self;
```

Comment: Sorry, I've just provide a value for NSLocationAlwaysUsageKey, I've also added you If selctor and It's wrong again..

Comment: Do you get any warnings on the console?  Are you running on the simulator or a real device?  Are you actually receiving the permission prompt from iOS?  Have you tried deleting your app and then running it?

Comment: There isn't any warnings, I use real device

Comment: Where do you initialise self.mapview?

Comment: In .h
@property (nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;

Comment: Have you checked the privacy settings in your device for your app - if location permission is denied there then you will never be prompted.

Comment: Location is setted on "Always" for my app

Comment: Now run, I don't know how, but run, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if i understand your problem.

if your problem is about the map is not show, you need to set frame of your map.

```
self.mapView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
```

hope i could help you

Comment: Nope, the map is just drawn, but I am not able to show my location and I don't know why this happened, because the code seems right.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use the -locationManager:didUpdateLocations method provided by CLLocationManagerDelegate.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations 
{
    [self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
    // Move this line here
    self.mapView.showsUserLocation = YES; 
}
```

After calling `[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation]` in ViewDidLoad, you shouldn't set `self.mapView.showsUserLocation` to `YES` yet as permission to use location services is not yet approved. Use the delegate to wait/get a location update from the system before setting `self.mapView.showsUserLocation` to `YES`.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to enable location services

```
if([CLLocationManager resolveClassMethod:@selector(locationServicesEnabled)]) {
    [CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled];
}
```